# Getting more helpful tab completion prompts in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, prompt, command-line-interface

Let's say I have a directory with a few files in it like this:

```
$ ls
file1  file2  file3
```

And I want to do some tab completion in bash:

```
$ cat file<tab>
file1  file2  file3
```

I remember seeing someone doing tab completion and the shell bolded the next parts, so in this case, it would bold the `1`, `2` and `3` of the filename so it'll look like this:  file**1**  file**2** file**3**

which will tell you what you should type in next.

I think this was a feature of `zsh`, but is there any way to get it in `bash`?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of directly ported functionality, but there is a way to hack this in `bash`. [Programmable completion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Programmable-Completion) allows you to specify what you'd like to see when you hit that tab key dependent on the calling program, allowing (as a popular example) `ssh` [tab] to show autocomplete options from `~/.ssh/known_hosts`.

Here are some useful resources:

[Intro, Source and RPMs](http://www.caliban.org/bash/#completion)

[User contributed "completions"](http://freshmeat.net/projects/bashcompletion/)

[More examples](http://linux.byexamples.com/archives/275/cli-magic-programable-bash-completion/)

[And more examples](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/more-using-bash-complete-command)

Of course, to duplicate the functionality you specify above, you'll have to get down and dirty with the programmable aspect of completion and write your own functions. Ubuntu ships [its own set of user contributed completions](http://packages.ubuntu.com/jaunty/bash-completion), which are a good starting point.

Answer (score 2):

In Red Hat based distros there is a package bash-completion. This package fills the /etc/bash_completion.d/ directory with specific completion behaviour for several programs. I'm using it under Fedora, Red Hat and CentOS.

```
yum install bash-completion
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using `tcsh` because of a similar feature.

Here is my /etc/csh.cshrc file :

```
if ($?tcsh && $?prompt) then

   bindkey "\e[1~" beginning-of-line # Home
   bindkey "\e[7~" beginning-of-line # Home rxvt
   bindkey "\e[2~" overwrite-mode    # Ins
   bindkey "\e[3~" delete-char       # Delete
   bindkey "\e[4~" end-of-line       # End
   bindkey "\e[8~" end-of-line       # End rxvt

   bindkey -k up history-search-backward
   bindkey -k down history-search-forward

   set filec
   set prompt="[%B%m%b:%~] %n%# "
   set complete = enhance            # important line
   set autolist                      # important line too
   alias ls 'ls -hA --color'
   alias ll 'ls -l'
endif
```